# numpy: get ndarray's value from an index array

Tags: python, numpy

I have high dimension numpy array, the dimension of the array is not fixed. I need to retrieve the value with a index list, the length of the index list is the same as the dimension of the numpy array.

In other words, I need a function:

```
def get_value_by_list_index(target_array, index_list):
  # len(index_list) = target_array.ndim
  # target array can be in any dimension
  # return the element at index specified on index list
```

For example, for a 3-dimension array, `data` and a list [i1, i2, i3], I the function should return `data[i1][i2][i3]`.

Is there a good way to achieve this task?

Comment: `target_array[tuple(index_list)]` which is the same as `target_array[i1,i2,i3]`

Comment: @hpaulj uff, I didn't even know that; what an API nightmare: let `idx=[1,2]` be our index list, then `arr[idx]` gives the second and third row of a matrix, but if `idx=(1,2)`, the same statement yields the second row, third column element

Comment: Often in python, list and tuple can be used interchangably, but in array indexing  the difference is significant.  It's the comma that makes a tuple, more so than the `()`, which are just used to reduce ambiguities. @MarcusMüller

Comment: @hpaulj fully aware of that, it's just that the type sensitivity to the index container being a tuple or any other iterable is a bit of a footgun if you're passing these around through an API. This is more of a realization than a hm, numpy critique, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the ndarray is actually containing a type that is just  a number well-representable by python types:

```py
source_array.item(*index_iterable)
```

will do the same.

If you need to work with ndarrays of more complex types that might not have a python built-in type representation, things are harder.

You could implement exactly what you sketch in your comment:

```
data[i1][i2][i3]
```

```py
# note that I didn't like the name of your function
def get_value_by_index_iterable(source_array, index_iterable):
  subarray = source_array
  for index in index_iterable:
    subarray = subarray[index]
  return subarray
```